# TYPO3: MenuProcessor cache configuration

Tags: typo3, typoscript

According to the current TYPO3 documentation the MenuProcessor utilizes the HEMNU and therefore it should be possible to use properties of HMENU in the Typoscript of the MenuProcessor.

HMENU has a property "cache" of data type "cache" that allows to set up the cache key, for example.

Unfortunately I get an "Invalid argument" exception when I assign "cache" to my MenuProcessor.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

- Completely disable the cache for my MenuProcessor

OR

- Set up a unique cache.key

Is there a way to to that?

Comment: would you min sharing your code as well?

Answer (score 1):

The MenuProcessor uses a `HEMNU` but does not support all properties.

Let have a look into the code of the [MenuProcessor](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/ad7227df0b3dda1f93ff728e791f8380124cc05d/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/DataProcessing/MenuProcessor.php#L86):

```
/**
 * Allowed configuration keys for menu generation, other keys
 * will throw an exception to prevent configuration errors.
 *
 * @var array
 */
public $allowedConfigurationKeys = [
    'cache_period',
    'entryLevel',
    'entryLevel.',
    'special',
    'special.',
    'minItems',
    'minItems.',
    'maxItems',
    'maxItems.',
    'begin',
    'begin.',
    'alternativeSortingField',
    'alternativeSortingField.',
    'showAccessRestrictedPages',
    'showAccessRestrictedPages.',
    'excludeUidList',
    'excludeUidList.',
    'excludeDoktypes',
    'includeNotInMenu',
    'includeNotInMenu.',
    'alwaysActivePIDlist',
    'alwaysActivePIDlist.',
    'protectLvar',
    'addQueryString',
    'addQueryString.',
    'if',
    'if.',
    'levels',
    'levels.',
    'expandAll',
    'expandAll.',
    'includeSpacer',
    'includeSpacer.',
    'as',
    'titleField',
    'titleField.',
    'dataProcessing',
    'dataProcessing.',
];
```

It is possible that when the cache property for `HMENU` was introduced in TYPO3 v10, it was simply forgotten to allow it in the MenuProcessor...

Comment: So it should be possible to create a Custom Processor by extending the MenuProcessor and adding cache to the $allowedConfigurationKeys array?

Comment: I was just interested and did a little research... A Custom Processor could be a try. The better way would be reporting it - maybe there are reasons *why* `cache` had not been included.

Comment: Created a forge issue: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/98985